# Raising custom Errors in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, autoload

I have added

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

to my `application.rb` file within the module & added a file

`lib/my_app_name.rb` containing

```
module MyAppName
  class MyError < StandardError
  end
end
```

But when I try to raise the error from my model like this

```
raise MyAppName::MyError, "There was a problem"
```

It returns this...

```
uninitialized constant MyAppName::MyError
```

I feel like the file is loaded from my lib directory because i'm using other files autoloaded from there, but can't seem to work out why the error is not recognized.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: This won't work as you have not created proper directory structure. You need to create my_app_name/my_error.rb, then autoload will work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I have a module included in my app in a similar way, and I reference methods in it like so:

```
modulename.methodname
```

I know that you are declaring a class in the module so this is a bit different than my situation, but have you tried this way of raising your error?

```
MyAppName.MyError
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply readyornot but it looks like it was more a directory structure issue in my situation which Kuldeep solved.

Comment: No problem, glad your code is working. For reference, my module .rb file is in lib/helpers.